# Question about the multiplicative inverse of a p-adic number

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, p-adic-number-theory

I am reading the text of Gouvea about p-adic numbers and I am trying to show that every $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}_{p}$ has a multiplicative inverse. In the case where $$\alpha =\sum_{i\geq 0}a_{i}p^{i}, \ \text{where} \ a_{0}\neq 0$$ I think I understood the logic, but the other case is a problem for me. For example, if I would like to find the inverse of the 5-adic number
$$\alpha =3\cdot 5 + 4\cdot 25$$
what would be the strategy? Because I really don't see how I can find a $5$-adic number which can give me $1$...
Can someone help me? Thanks before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inverse will not be a $5$-adic *integer*.  So its expansion will have one or more negaive powers of $5$.

Your number is $5$ times $3+4\cdot 5$.  If you invert $3+4\cdot 5$, and multiply that result by $5^{-1}$, you get the inverse of $3\cdot 5 + 4\cdot 5^2$.

Comment: I think that the inverse is $2\cdot 5^{-1} -3 +4\cdot 5$. So the general strategy is to take $p(a_{1} + a_{2} p + a_{3}p²+...)$ ?

Comment: You need some dots after it: The inverse of $3\cdot 5 + 4\cdot 5^2$ is $2\cdot 5^{-1} -3 +4\cdot 5+\dots$.  This inverse is **not** a rational with denominator a power of $5$, so no finite sum $\sum a_j 5^j$ can represent it.

Comment: If I want a representation where every $a_{j}\in\{ 0,1,\ldots ,p-1\}$ the inverse is $2\cdot 5^{-1} + 2+ 3\cdot 5+3\cdot 5^{2} +5^{3}+\dots$ Right?